# Divide with commas columns with variable spacing to create a manipulable DF

Tags: python, pandas

I have a txt with values that  originally looked like this.

```
D276            31386                         10610                         12122021 00:00:47840 85         0.00+842646    M000395708109323               ACTIVE CARD CHECK      844-6593879   NY           59655              840  6511011091718056           
D276            31386                         10610                         12122021 00:00:59840Y00         5.36-842647    M527021000201360               Etsy.com - TheCraftyCa Brooklyn      NY           56995              840  6511011091718056           
D276            86495                         29807                         12122021 00:08:22840N51        11.99-842648    M248747000103177               GOOGLE *YouTubePremium g.co/helppay# CA           78295              840  6511016547548056           
D276            29969                         10038                         12122021 00:27:19840 57        11.30-842649    M000445474354997               SPOTIFY                NEW YORK      NY           48995              840  6511010952148056           
D276            62521                         21152                         12122021 00:28:54840N51         5.40-842650    M527021000211443               Google Play            Mountain View CA           58175              840  6511014173278056           
D276            802                           701                           12122021 00:30:38840Y00        49.67-842651    M235251000762203               AMZN Mktp US           Amzn.com/bill WA           59425              840  6511010003058056           
D276            114710                        41280                         12122021 00:31:22840Z00        21.92-842652    M000445488848992               DD *DOORDASH MCDONALDS SAN FRANCISCO CA           58125              840  6511019296778056           
D276            125175                        45529                         12122021 00:31:50840Y05         0.00+842653    M145376000144509               PLAYSTATION NETWORK    800-345-7669  CA           58165              840  6511020299078056           
D276            125175                        45529                         12122021 00:32:07840Y57        21.44-842654    M145376000144509               PLAYSTATION NETWORK    800-345-7669  CA           58165              840  6511020299078056           
D276            125175                        45529                         12122021 00:32:08840Y57        21.44-842299    M527021000222747               PlaystationNetwork     San Mateo     CA           58185              840  6511020299078056           
D276            125175                        45529                         12122021 00:32:09840Y57        21.44-842300    M527021000222747               PlaystationNetwork     San Mateo     CA           58185              840  6511020299078056           
D276            125175                        45529                         12122021 00:32:09840 57         0.00+842655    MCARD ACCPT IDC                Sony - Playstation N.. St. Louis     USA          59695              840  6511020299078056           
D276            125175                        45529                         12122021 00:32:27840Y57        21.44-842301    M145376000144509               PLAYSTATION NETWORK    800-345-7669  CA           58165              840  6511020299078056           
D276            125175                        45529                         12122021 00:32:28840Y57        21.44-842657    M527021000222747               PlaystationNetwork     San Mateo     CA           58185              840  6511020299078056
```

It wasn't divided by commas and the spacing is variable, I tried several things like using regex trying to divide with commas the entries that had spacings bigger than 2 o 3.

```
data2= re.split(r'\s{3,}', data)
```

It was effective for most columns but in the middle I have a long string which varies for each operation and its spacing also does Ex.  Etsy.com - TheCraftyCa Brooklyn      NY    . In those cases my approach is ineffective and after that columns the other columns start to get mixed with the strings that the code can't isolate correctly .

I tried a different approach using

```
out_f = open(r"filesource.txt", mode="w")
writer = csv.writer(out_f)
with open(r'fileoutput.txt.csv') as in_f:
    for line in in_f:
        fields = line.strip("\n\r").split(",")
        d276_positions = [
            i
            for i, value in enumerate(fields)
            if i == 0 or value == "D276"
        ]
        d276_positions.append(len(fields))
        for start, end in zip(d276_positions, d276_positions[1:]):
            writer.writerow(fields[start:end])
```

It's effective at detect the start of each line, as all of them start with the same string (D276) but on the other hand it still have the same issue of the previous method at dividing the irregular strings as  GOOGLE *YouTubePremium g.co/helppay# CA .

I was doing some more research with re but I couldn't find a way to correctly split the the columns .

Any ideas or approach you would recommend with a txt like this one? i have around 10000 and in most of the cases the spacing varies in that exact same column.

Comment: Does every row start with D and then 3 numbers ('D276') or is it variable? I'm just having a hard time understanding where you want the rows split. Would be helpful if you could clarify.

Comment: You're right, sorry for not have being more precise, all rows start D276 , Being the last part of each line the long number Ex in the first line would be 840 6511011091718056 . In most of the cases each "column" is separated for not more that two spaces as in the cases of  10610 and   12122021 00:00:47840  (Time) but one of the columns  ACTIVE CARD CHECK 844-6593879 NY  have more than three spaces in somes cases causing the issue commented in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is a rough spot to be in. The data is basically semi-structured given that the delimiters are also found in the values. I think you're struck using a regular expression. I can't recommend regex101.com enough to help you build a regex that captures groups. Then you can use [pandas.Series.str.extract(regex, expand=True)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to separate out the capture groups. It will probably take some troubleshooting to get all your patterns matching correctly.

I think you can build an easy regex by just using start/stop points and positive look aheads that shouldn't be to tough to make work. Something like the following may be a good starting point.

[image]